# How can I use horizontal scroll to mimic slide to delete on macOS?

Tags: javascript, macos

When using the macOS Mail or Messages app you can swipe left or right with two fingers on the trackpad to delete a conversation or do some other action. (it's similar to the effect in iOS Messages)

I thought about making the HTML container of the element twice as long and then scrolling it to the center using JavaScript. This would allow horizontal scrolling which I could then apply an event listener to.

Is there a better way to do this? Or some framework that does it?

How would I achieve this behavior in JavaScript so it works well on macOS and iOS (and preferably all other platforms as well)?

Comment: It might be tricky to get a swipe working on macOS because the trackpad doesn't really behave like that in browsers. There are plenty of JavaScript gesture libraries out there, like https://zingchart.github.io/zingtouch/.

Also check this out: https://medium.com/@auchenberg/detecting-multi-touch-trackpad-gestures-in-javascript-a2505babb10e

Comment: @jcdl Sadly I couldn't get any of the examples you provided to work properly. Not on the iOS simulator and not on my Desktop